# ngram vectorization - if new token found which not exists in corpus, what should I do with it

Tags: nlp, vectorization, dictvectorizer

I'm building custom ngram vectorizer for bag of word model. I'm qurious - what should I do if during vectorizing of a short text I found new token, which not exists in corpus vocabulary. Should it be just skipped or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either skip it or you can add a special token to the vocabulary for unknown words, e.g. previously unseen words are replaced with `"UNK"` and then you can count them just the same as any other word. Also, to deal with the problem of not having any `UNK`s in the training data, you can replace all words that only occur once in the corpus with `UNK`.